# How to decode these strings?

Tags: json, decode, encode

We detect that client sides POST the following form:

```
{"json":"uTJERxU6soa0lbJZaAWEYGGwp4xOe0nN\/wORZ1Rnf5EJ2Z\/yc8UOWD1SDzTwXf1B"}
```

, and

```
{"json":"ppWzKIag6L\/nM6Dp5JFR1QAKcvxK9DFwIy49LbCHUWedfnvGhs4xYuivb+oF0q0r7TmofgGpk8tGUik1nB5HSilHzZDQIb2ay577V2bs8dKQKy\/KfWMLs1\/sVqg+Lgsvps7RTyK7jvxkTkZ6LldrkQ=="}
```

Since the key name is `json`, I guess the value is the result of encoded json data. The question is **how** the original json data were encoded, and **what** are the original value?

I tried to decode these strings by `base64`, but I failed or just got some unreadable code. Anyone can help? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it a file?

Comment: I think it's binary file. I was wondering if it's possible to find out its file type or readable data.